# Why are my physical devices running old APK, but emulator runs updated APK?

Tags: android, android-studio, deployment, adb

I have 2 physical devices and 1 emulator (genymotion) attached to ADB for deployments from Android Studio. Usually, they all work just fine. However, the two physical devices are not showing updated code changes, rather they are showing an old apk with old code every time I run from Android Studio. I have tried reconnecting them, and tried uninstalling the old APK, but they still show the old changes. The emulator works fine. What happened?

**UPDATE (2:00PM MST) :**
The same issue is happening on all emulators (and devices) running Android 5.0 or higher. The emulator running 4.4.4 is doing just fine. Now I'm really confused, especially since everything was working just fine this morning.

Comment: Have you tried disable instant run ?

Comment: faced same problem some time ago, just uninstall old apk before install the new one...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs as stated in my original post, that did not help. Instant Run has always been disabled.

Comment: clean and build project before install again

Comment: and like fimanslash said, turn off instant run: File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run

Comment: @Opiatefuchs as I already stated in the comments, Instant Run has always been off.

Comment: Please see updated post.

Comment: ok, maybe it could be important what are the changes in your code? And how did you see that the old APK is running. There must be an important detail that you hadn´t seen...can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Yes, I'm on mobile right now, and away from my IDE,but I can tell you that I changed a layout file dealing with collapsing toolbar layout, and that is when this started happening. I can change other things like the name of the app and other strings in my code, and those changes will happen; so I know that a new APK is being generated, but the code in that APK is not being updated in accordance with the changes I am making. By the way, on KitKat it works just fine. It's once you get to lollipop and higher that the changes aren't being made. I appreciate any insight